# Нахождение координат точки

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия, координаты, тригонометрия

есть задача. Мне даны координаты точки(камеры)(x0, y0, z0) в трехмерном пространстве, направление ее взгляда(угол поворота по окружности - вид сверху(ax) и вид сбоку(ay)(поворот влево/вправо и поворот вверх/вниз). Из камеры по направлению взгляда нарисовали отрезок длинной d. Вопрос заключается в нахождении координаты конечной точки. Все вышеперечисленные величины даны по условию. Напишите пожалуйста формулу для нахождения координат этой точки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

У вас как-то странно ориентированы оси и углы непонятны. Вообще-то это все - обычная сферическая система координат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в ней

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только и того, что к указанным координатам x, y, z вы должны добавить сооnветственно x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>0</sub> (обычный параллельный перенос).

Вообще-то это все требует только начального знания тригонометрии, не более того, так что ученик примерно 9 класса с задачей справиться обязан...